Nextflow Best Practice When Collecting a Large Number of Files in One Step
Consider a hypothetical pipeline shown below, where many files need to be collected at one stage in the pipeline:

It seems like the idiomatic way of accomplishing this is to pass Process B a list of filenames, which then passes those file names to the tool in question:
workflow {
    channel_with_many_files = channel.of(...)

    PROCESS_A(channel_with_many_files)
    
    all_files_together = PROCESS_A.out.collect()

    PROCESS_B(all_files_together)
}

And then in the process B definition:
process PROCESS_B{
    input:
    path(all_files_list)

    output:
    path(single_output_file)
    
    script:

    """
    ./mytool ${all_files_list}
    """
}

The problem with this, in my opinion, is that when n (number of files) grows to be very large (say > 2000), the command that is generated in PROCESS_B is unweidly and a bit messy.
Is this the way to deal with such a pattern in Nextflow, or is there a better way?

A better way would be to stage the files in a sub-directory, which would allow you to simply pass in a glob pattern to your tool. This can be achieved using the path input type and a string containing the * or ? wildcards to control the names of staged files1. Here, the files are named as the source files in a sub-directory called 'staged':
process PROCESS_B{

    input:
    path 'staged/*'

    script:
    """
    mytool staged/*
    """
}

Note that you can also use the stageAs option for this, if a variable is somehow useful:
process PROCESS_B{

    input:
    path all_files_list, stageAs: 'staged/*'

    script:
    """
    echo "Staged ${all_files_list.size()} files..."
    mytool staged/*
    """
}


Oh man, I can't believe I missed this in the docs. This is very elegant. Thank you!
